# PHP - DomDocument->saveXML ничего не выводит

Tags: php, dom

Есть xml файл mv.xml
Пытаюсь вывести всю информацию из него

```
$doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$doc->load('mv.xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

И на выходе ничего не выводит, пытался писать

```
var_dump($doc->saveXML());
```

Выводит - string(1309) " "

Comment: вы проверьте что `load`  возвращает

Comment: возвращает bool(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($doc->saveXML());
```